# "Came across" vs "comes across"

Tags: grammar, word-choice, differences

What's the difference between "came across" and "comes across" when used in the following sentence? Are both correct?

> Steve Irwin tells the story of a boy who was walking through a swamp when he **[came | comes]** across a crocodile. The boy was trying to get home, but the crocodile started following him ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*... came across*" is clearly correct, merely another clause in a sequence describing past events.

in "*comes across*", the change of tense transfers the mind of the reader from the present, as they read about a series of past events, to the instant in the past when important things happened. The change attempts to put the reader into the circumstances as they appeared at that instant.

"*... a boy was walking through a swamp, when he comes across a crocodile ...*" does this effectively. We transfer from an comfortable armchair read to suddenly experiencing the perilous event as immediate and pressing.

From that perspective, "*comes across*" is correct. I, not being a creative writer,  expected the present tense to continue in the following prose. It does not, as if Irwin then wants to relax the reader.

Comment: No; switches to the historic present (and back) should not be made so abruptly, mid-sentence.